# Error in reading Excel file & Insert data into MySQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

My purpose is to read an excel (.xls) file and store it in the database as well as show the inputs of excel file in the browser.

I am facing problem while reading the file. I have integrated [Excelfilereader.php](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader/blob/master/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php)

The program reads the excel file but while printing its output in (excel file content) in the browser, data print in zig-zag way.

Example:

**studentid**  **name** **class** **school** **course** **address** [name of fields]

In Browser, the same fields are printed, but the data of **studentID** is printed under the **name**, data of **name** prints under **class**, but rest all are printed as it is. In first two columns are printed unaligned.

Code used to call Excelreader.php:

```
[mysql_query("insert into submit_form(parent_id,name,lab,submission,title,sampletype,file) values('','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['lab']."','".$_POST['submission']."','".$_POST['title']."','".$_POST['sampletype']."','".$uploadfile."')");
$insertid=mysql_insert_id();
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
//echo "Total Sheets in this xls file: ".count($data->sheets)."<br /><br />";

$html="<table border='1'>";
for($i=0;$i<count($data->sheets);$i++) // Loop to get all sheets in a file.
{   
    if(count($data->sheets[$i][cells])>0) // checking sheet not empty
    {
    //echo "Sheet $i:<br /><br />Total rows in sheet $i  ".count($data->sheets[$i][cells])."<br />";
        for($j=2;$j<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells]);$j++) // loop used to get each row of the sheet
        { 
            $html.="<tr>";
            for($k=1;$k<=count($data->sheets[$i][cells][$j]);$k++) // This loop is created to get data in a table format.
            {
                $html.="<td>";
                $html.=$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][$k];
                $html.="</td>";
            }
            $data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][1];
            $eid = $eid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][1]);
            $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][2]);
            $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][3]);
            $ethnic = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][4]);
            $cancer = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][5]);
            $sample = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][6]);
            $instrument = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][7]);
            $instrumenttype = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][8]);
            $query = "insert into submit_form(parent_id,name,lab,submission,title,patient,age,gender,ethnic,cancer,sample,instrument,instrumenttype,attach,sampletype,file) values('".$insertid."','".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['lab']."','".$_POST['submission']."','".$_POST['title']."','".$eid."','".$age."','".$gender."','".$ethnic."','".$cancer."','".$sample."','".$instrument."','".$instrumenttype."','1','".$_POST['sampletype']."','".$uploadfile."')";

            mysqli_query($connection,$query);

            $html.="</tr>";
        }
    }][2]
```

Comment: patient  age       gender     ethnic       university  
                 1       23MALE     berlin       xavier 
                 2           25FEMALE    munchen   xavier ........ and so on ,,

Comment: any other solutions please ?

Comment: Ah, so gender and age are grouped together? What is the outcome of $data->sheets[$i][cells][$j] when you dump it?

Comment: You've tagged this with "phpMyAdmin" so I suggest you use the phpMyAdmin Import tab; the easiest way is probably to do a CSV export from Excel and import in to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed `mysql_*` calls with `mysqli_*` calls.  Use *only* `mysqli_*` calls.

(And you should escape the `$_POST[]` columns, too.  They are vulnerable to hackers.)

Comment: where I have used mysql_* instead of mysqli_* ??